# applying array of function to array of elements by position

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, functional-programming, numpy-ndarray

Assume the following:

```
def x2(x):
    res=x*x
    return res

def tx(x):
    res=2*x
    return res

def x3(x):
    res=x*x*x
    return res

x=np.array([1,2,3])
f=np.array([x2,tx,x3])
```

Im trying to return an array that is array([x2(1),tx(2),x3(3)]) without using a for loop. 
Is this possible in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no objective reason to do it, but you can do it like that :

```
@np.vectorize
def apply(f,x) : return  f(x)
```

Then `apply(f,x)` is now `[1,4,27]`

Comment: Why is there no reason to do it this way ?

Comment: because no acceleration is done. numpy is efficient wen you do same computation on large aligned arrays. If you change the function each time, you win nothing.

Comment: Note `np.vectorize` is just a Python-level loop, its use is for convenience only.

Answer (score -1):

No, in the *general* case a Python-level `for` loop is unavoidable.

But you can hide it behind `map` + `lambda`:

```
res1 = list(map(lambda x: x[0](x[1]), zip((x2, tx, x3), x)))
res2 = np.array([x2(1), tx(2), x3(3)])

assert np.array_equal(res1, res2)
```

Of course, a list comprehension is recommended in this situation:

```
res = [func(var) for func, var in zip((x2, tx, x3), x)]
```